# Spotfire DropDown list to filter entire page?

Tags: drop-down-menu, dashboard, tibco, spotfire

I have been desperately trying to figure out how to take a column, customer name, and be able make a drop down list that filters the entire pages visualizations so that when you have a specif customer selected it filters everything.

I think I'm going down the right path my creating a property type string and setting it to unique values in that customer name column, but cant seem to figure out what to do next.  Even if i have to set it individually for each visualization that would be fine, but i cant seem to get this to work.

Can someone help me figure this out?

I'm on spotfire 7.0 if that matters.  Thanks

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

@TPLEE - In order to apply filter to the visualization from the selected drop down, you have to insert the below case statement in 'Limit data using expression' section of the visualization properties as shown below.

- Right click on the visualization and go to properties.
- Click on edit as shown in the picture and insert the below case
  statement and click 'Ok'.

*Note: 'YourCOLUMNName' will be your column name from the data table that you are using and ${CustomerName} is your property control name*

```
case
when "${CustomerName}"=[YourCOLUMNName] then true
when "${CustomerName}"="" then true
else false end
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer but it should say all values versus "" for all customers. Alternatively this is redundant to just adding a drop down filter so I'd suggest that as well. +1 from me if you do

Comment: Thanks, that works. It's beyond me why this is so hidden/convoluted in a product that displays data from a database...